# Mining on Mecer Xtreme S01 PC-On-Stick?

Tags: cpu-mining, mining-software, mining-hardware

The Mecer Xtreme S01 PC-On-Stick comes with an Intel Bay Trail Quad Core Z3735F CPU. Is it possible to mine Monero on this device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, since Z3735F has x86_64 instruction set.

But there is no AES so you will get a very small hash rate, and considering its design, it will probably overheat, so most probably not worth it.